# Why are some values in the pandas dataframe becoming integers from strings after I add a column to the dataframe manually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have made a pandas dataframe from a CSV file like so:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
```

In it, there's a column called `CLASS`. These are the values contained in `CLASS`:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(CLASS)
Out [1]: Counter({'1': 60783, '2': 37313, '3': 2564, '4': 959, ' ': 346, 'D': 27})
```

Now, I add a column to the dataframe manually, and save it in a new csv:

```
data['DURATION'] = DURATION
data.to_csv('new_dataset.csv')
```

Then, when I open the new CSV and check the values in `CLASS`, some of them have become integers!

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('new_dataset.csv')
CLASS = dataset['OCCUP_CLASS']
Counter(CLASS)
Out [1]: Counter({' ': 346,
                  1: 48418,
                  '1': 12365,
                  2: 16189,
                  '2': 21124,
                  3: 848,
                  '3': 1716,
                  4: 81,
                  '4': 878,
                  'D': 43})
```

Why is this happening? This creates problems as I cannot plot or make histograms of `CLASS` anymore, while before I was able to do so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(CLASS)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-b6bafcfd7ad5> in <module>()
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 2 plt.plot(CLASS)

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3356                       mplDeprecation)
   3357     try:
-> 3358         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3359     finally:
   3360         ax._hold = washold

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1853                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1854                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1855             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1856 
   1857         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1526 
   1527         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
-> 1528             self.add_line(line)
   1529             lines.append(line)
   1530 

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in add_line(self, line)
   1930             line.set_clip_path(self.patch)
   1931 
-> 1932         self._update_line_limits(line)
   1933         if not line.get_label():
   1934             line.set_label('_line%d' % len(self.lines))

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _update_line_limits(self, line)
   1952         Figures out the data limit of the given line, updating self.dataLim.
   1953         """
-> 1954         path = line.get_path()
   1955         if path.vertices.size == 0:
   1956             return

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in get_path(self)
    949         """
    950         if self._invalidy or self._invalidx:
--> 951             self.recache()
    952         return self._path
    953 

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in recache(self, always)
    655         if always or self._invalidy:
    656             yconv = self.convert_yunits(self._yorig)
--> 657             y = _to_unmasked_float_array(yconv).ravel()
    658         else:
    659             y = self._y

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in _to_unmasked_float_array(x)
   2048         return np.ma.asarray(x, float).filled(np.nan)
   2049     else:
-> 2050         return np.asarray(x, float)
   2051 
   2052 

c:\users\h473\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    490 
    491     """
--> 492     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    493 
    494 

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Adding the first 20 rows of the 2 relevant columns from the dataset:

```
DURATION    CLASS
10          1
14          1
-1          1
-1          1
0           1
-1          1
14          2
8           2
-1          1
14          3
-1          3
-1          
-1          4
-1          4
-1          3
8           1
-1          2
-1          2
-1          1
```

**EDIT 2:** Output of `print(dataset['CLASS'].value_counts())`:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', dtype={'CLASS': str})
print(dataset['CLASS'].value_counts())

1    48418
2    21124
2    16189
1    12365
3     1716
4      878
3      848
       346
4       81
D       43
Name: CLASS, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT 3:** Plotting is not a problem for blank elements, as shown with the following plot with the original data, where the blank point on x-axis is highlighted:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post some data from the csv (and better not an image of it)

Comment: what is the `dtype` of `dataset['OCCUP_CLASS']` ? can you share the result of `dataset['OCCUP_CLASS'].dtype` ?

Comment: @U8-Forward I can't really post some data from the CSV as it is confidential, but I have edited the question to include the first 20 rows of the 2 relevant columns.

Comment: @Kristada673 I think it is not working because one element is a `''`

Comment: @nimrodz The output of `CLASS.dtype` for both before and after is the same, `dtype('O')`. And the output of `dataset.dtypes` for both before and after insertion of the extra column shows `CLASS` as `object.`

Comment: @U8-Forward But the question is, when I added an extra column, `DURATION`, and did not even touch the `CLASS` column, why did some of the elements in `CLASS` change from string to integers?

Comment: @Kristada673 It's because when you want to plot something it always converts it into a float

Comment: @U8-Forward Its not about when it wants to plot something. I mentioned in the question that when I check how many unique elements (and occurrences of each) are present in `CLASS` with `Counter(CLASS)`, it shows the integer versions of the same elements in addition to the string versions. That means, some of the elements got converted into int or float from string. This I don't understand why because I did not even touch the `CLASS` column!

Comment: Were the values in the CLASS column quoted in the original csv file? Like `"1"`?

Comment: @Rob When I open them in the CSV or in sublime text or notepad or print them out on the console, they don't look any different before and after - just the numbers, no quotes.

Comment: Just a remark: there is no need to use a `Counter`, you can get a Series of value counts by using `CLASS.value_counts()`

Comment: @Rob I have added a second edit to the question with the output of `CLASS.value_counts()` after forcing the dtype of the dataframe to be str. Interesting results.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas tries to detect the data type of a column, but sometimes fails as you noticed. You can force the data type of a column in `read_csv` like this:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('new_dataset.csv', dtype={'CLASS': str})
```

Comment: Well, this also gives this error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: `

Comment: Of course you get an error during plotting, what do you expect to see for strings like " " or "D"? You can plot for example the value_counts instead with `CLASS.value_counts().hist()`.

Comment: If you instead want to plot only the numeric values, use something like `pd.to_numeric(CLASS, errors='coerce').plot()`

Comment: I have included a third edit in the question details to show that blanks do not cause problem for plotting.

Comment: You did not make that plot with `plt.plot(CLASS)`, since it is a histogram of the data. Try it with `CLASS.hist()` or `CLASS.value_counts().plot()`, my first comment is an error.

Comment: I used `plt.hist(CLASS)` for that, and I am just showing that as an example. I can show a similar plot for `plt.plot` on the old dataset. In the new dataset, both give the same error.

Comment: You can also force the dtype after reading by using `CLASS = CLASS.astype(str)`

Comment: After doing `CLASS = CLASS.astype(str)`, and then checking the `value_counts()`, I get the identical output as in EDIT 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173115/discussion-between-rob-and-kristada673).